# save / retreive background color to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

How to insert the color value into sql DB onclick function from select option? I have a dropdown list that change the background color on some cells in my table but if I refresh the page the background color is disappeared...
for your info I ve setted

```
 <td style="background-color:<?php echo $row['mycolor'] ?>"><?php echo $row['mydata'] ?></td>
```

so i need to save and retreive the background color after selection from dropdown.  THX

```
        <select id = "aircraft-state" onchange="setcolour(event,this.value)">
            <option selected="please select" >please select</option>
            <option value = "airborne" value="#4286f4"name="airborne" onClick="save(this);">airborne</option>
            <option value = "landed" value="#7eff47" name="landed" onClick="save(this);">landed</option>
        </select>


<script >
  function setcolour(e,v){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    switch( v ){
        case 'airborne':
            tr.childNodes[17].style.backgroundColor='#4286f4';
        break;
        case 'landed':
            tr.childNodes[17].style.backgroundColor='#7eff47';
        break;
 } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can do it with the help of ajax.

Answer (score 0):

try this ajax call...

```
<script>

$("#aircraft-state").on('change',function(){

var $form = $(this).closest('form');
var data = {}; // your color value send it with ajax form
$.ajax({
    url : $form.attr('action'), //url of ajax php file
    type: $form.attr('method'), // method ex. GET|POST
    data : {action: 'change_color' , color_value : $("#aircraft-state").val()")},
    success: function(response) {
    //do your success operation for color change here ...
    $("td").css('background-color', response.color_value);
    }
   });
});
</script>
```

and on php ajax file do this code

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'change_color')
{
  $color_value = $_POST['color_value'];
  //write your database update query here
  echo $color_value;exit;
}
```